# Option clash with setspace.sty

Tags: line-spacing, msword, setspace

I'm having trouble with adjusting the space between lines. I need the exact 1,5 MS Word like spacing. I found out that I'd have to adjust the     `\setstretch{}`. For that I loaded a modified version of the setspace.sty. I only made following changes:

```
\newcommand{\onehalfspacing}{% MSWORD SETTINGS
\setstretch{1.44}%  default
\ifcase \@ptsize \relax % 10pt
\setstretch {1.448}%
\or % 11pt
\setstretch {1.399}%
\or % 12pt
\setstretch {1.433}%
\fi
}

\newcommand{\doublespacing}{% MSWORD SETTINGS
\setstretch {1.92}%  default
\ifcase \@ptsize \relax % 10pt
\setstretch {1.936}%
\or % 11pt
\setstretch {1.866}%
\or % 12pt
\setstretch {1.902}%
\fi
}
```

I tested my modification with a simple code (I had the modified version of the setspace.sty in the project folder:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\onehalfspacing
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

It worked fine. The problem started when I tried to apply this to my document. 
I'm using the `\documentclass{Hausarbeit-jura}`. When I try to compile with my changes I get the following error

> setspace.sty Command \onehalfspacing already defined

I think the `\documentclass{Hausarbeit-jura}`already defined the `\onehalfsize` command but I can't find where.

I'd be really grateful if someone could give me a hint.
I'm using following preamble:

```
\documentclass{hausarbeit-jura}


%
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\addto\captionsngerman{\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Gliederung}}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{jurabase}
\usepackage{jurabib}
%\usepackage{etex}%if many packages loaded
\bibliographystyle{jurabib}
\usepackage{txnewbie}
%\usepackage{setspace}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % Kein Einzug nach Absätzen
 %
 %
 %
%\frontmatter
%\pagenumbering{Roman}
%
%
%
    \title{Hausarbeit}
    \subtitle{Übung im Zivilrecht für Anfänger}
    \author{text\\text\\Frankfurt%\\text\\text}
    }
    \matrikelnummer{111111}
    \semester[text]{text}
    \prof{text}
    \date{text}
    \maketitle
%   \pagenumbering{Roman}
%   \setcounter{page}{2}
\textbf{Fall 1}\\
\\TEXT\\
\\\textbf{Fall 2}\\
\\TEXT\\
\tableofcontents
\bibliography{zivii}
%\mainmatter
%\pagenumbering{arabic}
%
%
%
\onehalfspacing
%\TXonehalfspacing
%\setstretch{1.433}
\chapter{Anspruch des A gegen den U}
TEXT
%
 \section{Schuldverhältnis}
 TEXT
 %
    \subsection{Werkvertrag}
    TEXT.
    %
    \subsection{Zwischenergebnis}
    %
 \section{Pflichtverletzung}

 %
 \section{AGB-Haftungsauschluss}

 %
 \subsection{Anwendungsbereich}

 %
 \subsection{Vorliegen einer AGB}

 %
 \subsection{Einbeziehung}

 %
 \subsubsection{Ausdrücklicher Hinweis bei Vertragschluss}

 %
\subsubsection{Möglichkeit zumutbarer Kenntnisnahme}

%
\subsubsection{Einverständnis}

%
\subsubsection{Zwischenergebnis}

%
\subsection{Keine überraschende Klauseln}

%
\subsection{Auslegung der AGB}
%
\subsubsection{Keine vorrangige Individualabrede}

%
\subsubsection{Unklarheitsregel}

%
\subsubsection{Zwischenergebnis}

%
\subsection{Inhaltskontrolle}

\subsubsection{Inhalt der Klausel}

%
\subsubsection{Kontrollfähigkeit der Klausel}
%\end{spacing}{1.5}
\end{document}
```

This is the `Hausarbeit-jura.cls`

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{hausarbeit-jura}
[2016/04/25 v1.4 Eine Klasse für juristische Hausarbeiten (ao, ms)]
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\DeclareOption{american}{%
    \PassOptionsToPackage{american,ngerman}{babel}
    \AtBeginDocument{\ClassInfo{hausarbeit-jura}{Die Sprache Englisch (Amerikanisch) wurde
      zusätzlich aktiviert.}}
}
\DeclareOption{british}{%
    \PassOptionsToPackage{british,ngerman}{babel}
    \AtBeginDocument{\ClassInfo{hausarbeit-jura}{Die Sprache Englisch (Britisch) wurde
      zusätzlich aktiviert}}
}
\DeclareOption{english}{%
    \PassOptionsToPackage{british,ngerman}{babel}
    \AtBeginDocument{\ClassInfo{hausarbeit-jura}{Die Sprache Englisch (Britisch) wurde
      zusätzlich aktiviert}}
}
\DeclareOption{latin1}{\PassOptionsToPackage{latin1}{inputenc}}
\DeclareOption{utf8}{\PassOptionsToPackage{utf8}{inputenc}}
\DeclareOption{ansinew}{\PassOptionsToPackage{ansinew}{inputenc}}
\DeclareOption{applemac}{\PassOptionsToPackage{applemac}{inputenc}}
\newif\if@centerpagenumber
\@centerpagenumberfalse
\DeclareOption{centerpagenumber}{\AtBeginDocument{\@classiclayoutfalse}}%\@centerpagenumbertrue}
\newif\if@texgyre
\@texgyretrue
\DeclareOption{texgyre}{\@texgyretrue}
\DeclareOption{oldfonts}{\@texgyrefalse}
\newif\if@superscriptedition
\@superscripteditiontrue
\DeclareOption{nosuperscriptedition}{\@superscripteditionfalse}
\newif\if@varioref
\@varioreffalse
\DeclareOption{varioref}{\@varioreftrue}
\newif\if@headline
\@headlinefalse
\DeclareOption{headline}{\@headlinetrue}
\newif\if@headlinetitlepageleft
\@headlinetitlepageleftfalse
\DeclareOption{headlinetitlepageleft}{\@headlinetitlepagelefttrue}
\ExecuteOptions{american,utf8}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{jurabook}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,showpagenumber,classiclayout]{jurabook}[2007/11/09 V0.91 (beta) juridical books (AS)]
\RequirePackage{ifluatex}
\RequirePackage{ifxetex}
\ifxetex
   \RequirePackage{fontspec}
   \setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\else
   \ifluatex
      \RequirePackage{fontspec}
      \setmainfont{Times New Roman}
   \else
      \RequirePackage{inputenc}
      \RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
      \if@texgyre
         \usepackage{tgtermes}
         \usepackage[matchlowercase]{tgheros}
         \usepackage[matchlowercase]{tgcursor}
      \else
         \usepackage{mathptmx}
         \usepackage[scaled=0.91]{helvet}
         \usepackage{courier}
      \fi%
      \RequirePackage{textcomp}
      \RequirePackage{eurosym}
      \let\texteuro\euro
      \DeclareInputText{128}{\,\euro}
   \fi%
\fi%
\RequirePackage{babel}
\RequirePackage{indentfirst}
\RequirePackage{geometry}
\if@headline
   \geometry{left=7cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,footskip=0.5cm,marginparwidth=5cm,verbose,includehead}%
\else
   \geometry{left=7cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,footskip=0.5cm,marginparwidth=5cm,verbose}%
\fi%
\savegeometry{pagemainmatter}
\newgeometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm}
\savegeometry{pagefrontmatter}
\RequirePackage{ellipsis}
\RequirePackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\defineshorthand{"`}{\openautoquote}
\defineshorthand{"'}{\closeautoquote}
\RequirePackage[final,tracking=smallcaps,expansion=alltext,protrusion=true]{microtype}%
\SetTracking{encoding=*,shape=sc}{50}%
\if@headline
   \renewcommand{\SetJuboPagestyle}{%
      \pagestyle{fancy}%
      \fancyhf{}%
      \lhead{\@shortauthor{} -- \@matrikelnummer}%
      \if@centerpagenumber
         \cfoot{\thepage}%
      \else
         \rfoot{\thepage}%
      \fi%
      \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
   }%
\else
   \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
   \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
      \fancyhead{}%
      \if@centerpagenumber\else
         \fancyhf{}%
         \fancyfootoffset[RO,RE]{2cm}%
         \rfoot{\thepage}%
      \fi}%
   \AtBeginDocument{%
      \fancyhead{}}%
\fi%

\RequirePackage{jurabib}% Bibliografie
%\jbedseplikecite% Die Separation der Herausgeber im Literaturverzeichnis entspricht der im Zitat
%\jbdonotindexeditors
\renewcommand*{\bibatsep}{,}% Komma nach dem Titel des Buches oder des Artikels
\renewcommand*{\jbaensep}{,}% Komma nach der Auflage, vor dem Jahr
\renewcommand*{\bibbdsep}{}% kein Komma nach Ort und vor dem Jahr
\renewcommand*{\bibjtsep}{}% Komma vor dem Namen der Zeitschrift
\renewcommand*{\bibbtsep}{in:~}% für in collection, Komma vor dem Titel
\renewcommand*{\ajtsep}{}% Abstand nach dem Namen der Zeitschrift
\renewcommand*{\artnumberformat}{\unskip,\space H.~}% bei den Zeitschriften statt Nr. H.
\if@superscriptedition
   \jurabibsetup{%
      annotatorlastsep=/,%
      bibformat=tabular,%
      titleformat={all,commasep},% Komma vor dem Titel
      commabeforerest,% Komma vor der Seitenangabe in der Fußnote
      %superscriptedition=all,% Ausgabe oben
      howcited=all,%
      authorformat={dynamic}%
   }%
\else
   \jurabibsetup{%
      annotatorlastsep=divis,%
      bibformat=tabular,%
      titleformat={all,commasep}, %Komma vor dem Titel
      commabeforerest, %Komma vor der Seitenangabe in der Fußnote
      howcited=all,%
      authorformat={dynamic}%
      }%
\fi

\bibliographystyle{jurabib}
\bibtotoc               % Listet LitVerZ in Tableofcontents

\renewcommand*{\bibleftcolumn}{\textwidth/3}%
\renewcommand*{\bibrightcolumn}{\textwidth-\bibleftcolumn-0.5cm}%

\if@varioref%
   \usepackage[ngerman]{varioref}
   \vref@addto\extrasngerman{%
      \def\reftextafter {auf S.~\thevpagerefnum}%
      \def\reftextbefore{auf S.~\thevpagerefnum}}
   \renewcommand{\xref}[1]{% vereinfacht Zitierungen
   \ref{#1} \vpageref{#1}}
\fi%

%%% Anpassung der Zähler
\renewcommand\thechapter{\Alph{chapter}.}
\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}.}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}.}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\alph{subsubsection})}
\renewcommand\thesubfoursection{(\arabic{subfoursection})}
\renewcommand\thesubfivesection{(\alph{subfivesection})}
\renewcommand\thesubsixsection{(\alph{subsixsection}\alph{subsixsection})}
\renewcommand\thesubsevensection{(\alph{subsevensection}\alph{subsevensection}\alph{subsevensection})}
\renewcommand\thesubeightsection{(\roman{subeightsection})}

\renewcommand{\jubo@settocindents}{%
  \if@chapterprefix%
    \settowidth{\chapternumwidth}{\chaptername~999\chapterextra\space}% warum drei x 9? zweimal ist zu knapp
  \else% chaptersuffix:
    \settowidth{\chapternumwidth}{999.~\chaptername\chapterextra\space}%
  \fi%
  \settowidth{\sectionnumwidth}{III.\ }%
  \settowidth{\subsectionnumwidth}{8.\ }%
  \settowidth{\subsubsectionnumwidth}{b)\ }%
  \settowidth{\subthreesectionnumwidth}{bb)\ }%
  \settowidth{\subfoursectionnumwidth}{(8)\ }%
  \settowidth{\subfivesectionnumwidth}{(b)\ }%
  \settowidth{\subsixsectionnumwidth}{(bb)\ }%
  \settowidth{\subsevensectionnumwidth}{(bbb)\ }%
  \settowidth{\subeightsectionnumwidth}{(iii)\ }%
  \if@chapterprefix%
    \setlength{\sectiontocindent}{\chapternumwidth}%
  \else%
    \settowidth{\@tempdima}{\bfseries 99.\space}%
    \setlength{\sectiontocindent}{\@tempdima}%
  \fi
  \if@fixtocindent%
    \setlength{\sectiontocindent}{\jb@defaulttocindent@length}% = 1.5em per default
  \fi%
  \setlength{\subsectiontocindent}{\sectiontocindent}%
  \addtolength{\subsectiontocindent}{\sectionnumwidth}%
  \setlength{\subsubsectiontocindent}{\subsectiontocindent}%
  \addtolength{\subsubsectiontocindent}{\subsectionnumwidth}%
  \setlength{\subthreesectiontocindent}{\subsubsectiontocindent}%
  \addtolength{\subthreesectiontocindent}{\subsubsectionnumwidth}%
  \setlength{\subfoursectiontocindent}{\subthreesectiontocindent}%
  \addtolength{\subfoursectiontocindent}{\subthreesectionnumwidth}%
  \setlength{\subfivesectiontocindent}{\subfoursectiontocindent}%
  \addtolength{\subfivesectiontocindent}{\subfoursectionnumwidth}%
  \setlength{\subsixsectiontocindent}{\subfivesectiontocindent}%
  \addtolength{\subsixsectiontocindent}{\subfivesectionnumwidth}%

  \setlength{\subsevensectiontocindent}{\subsixsectiontocindent}%
  \addtolength{\subsevensectiontocindent}{\subsixsectionnumwidth}%

  \setlength{\subeightsectiontocindent}{\subsevensectiontocindent}%
  \addtolength{\subeightsectiontocindent}{\subsevensectionnumwidth}%

  \setlength{\paragraphtocindent}{\subeightsectiontocindent}%
  \addtolength{\paragraphtocindent}{\subeightsectionnumwidth}%

  \setlength{\subparagraphtocindent}{\paragraphtocindent}%
  \addtolength{\subparagraphtocindent}{\jb@defaulttocindent@length}%
}

%%% Kapitel anpassen
\renewcommand{\jb@chapter@style}{\LARGE\bfseries}
\setlength{\jb@chapterafter@length}{20\p@}
\setlength{\jb@chapterbefore@length}{15\p@}
%%%
%%% Abschnitte anpassen
\newlength{\sectionbefore}
\setlength{\sectionbefore}{-2ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}
\newlength{\sectionafter}
\setlength{\sectionafter}{1ex \@plus .1ex}
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection%
  {section}%
  {1}%
  {\z@}%
  {-2.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
  {1.7ex \@plus.15ex}%
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection%
  {subsection}%
  {2}%
  {\z@}%
  {\sectionbefore}%
  {\sectionafter}%
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\@startsection%
   {subsubsection}%
   {3}%
   {\z@}%
   {\sectionbefore}%
   {\sectionafter}%
   {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\renewcommand{\subthreesection}{\@startsection%
  {subthreesection}%
  {4}%
  {\z@}%
  {\sectionbefore}%
  {\sectionafter}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\let\subsubsubsection\subthreesection
\renewcommand*{\subfoursection}{\@startsection%
  {subfoursection}%
  {5}%
  {\z@}%
  {\sectionbefore}%
  {\sectionafter}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\let\subsubsubsubsection\subfoursection
\renewcommand*{\subfivesection}{\@startsection%
  {subfivesection}%
  {6}%
  {\z@}%
  {\sectionbefore}%
  {\sectionafter}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\let\subsubsubsubsubsection\subfivesection
\renewcommand*{\subsixsection}{\@startsection%
  {subsixsection}%
  {7}%
  {\z@}%
  {\sectionbefore}%
  {\sectionafter}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\let\subsubsubsubsubsubsection\subsixsection
\renewcommand*{\subsevensection}{\@startsection%
  {subsevensection}%
  {8}%
  {\z@}%
  {\sectionbefore}%
  {\sectionafter}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\let\subsubsubsubsubsubsubsection\subsevensection
\renewcommand*{\subeightsection}{\@startsection%
  {subeightsection}%
  {9}%
  {\z@}%
  {\sectionbefore}%
  {\sectionafter}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\let\subsubsubsubsubsubsubsubsection\subeightsection
%%%
\let\@ORIGfrontmatter\frontmatter
\renewcommand\frontmatter{\@ORIGfrontmatter%
\loadgeometry{pagefrontmatter}%
\onehalfspacing% muss nochmal gesetzt werden, da es sonst durch loadgeometry verloren geht
\reversemarginpar% muss nochmal gesetzt werden, da es sonst durch loadgeometry verloren geht
   \fancyfootoffset[RO]{0cm}%
   \pagestyle{fancyplain}%
   \if@headline\fancyheadoffset[L]{0pt}\fi}
\AtBeginDocument{\frontmatter}

\let\@ORIGmainmatter\mainmatter
\renewcommand\mainmatter{\@ORIGmainmatter%
   \loadgeometry{pagemainmatter}%
   \onehalfspacing%
   \reversemarginpar%
\fancyfootoffset[RO,RE]{0cm}%
   \if@headline\fancyheadoffset[L]{\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}\fi}
\renewcommand{\chapter}{%
  \ifnum\value{chapter}=0\mainmatter\fi% Automatisch auf Hauptteil umschalten
  \chapterlevel%
  \if@headline\else\jubo@thispagestyle@empty\fi%
  \global\@topnum\z@%
  \@afterindentfalse
  \secdef\@chapter\@schapter%
}

\newcommand{\setpg}[2][]{\setpgfront{#1}\setpgmain{#2}}
\newcommand{\setpgmain}[1]{\newgeometry{#1}\savegeometry{pagemainmatter}}
\newcommand{\setpgfront}[1]{\newgeometry{#1}\savegeometry{pagefrontmatter}}

%%% Kein § vor der Kapitelnummer; korrekte Abstände
\renewcommand{\make@jubo@chaptercomplete}{%
  \if@chapterprefix%
    \renewcommand{\jubo@chaptercomplete}{\thechapter\chapterextra}
  \else%
    \renewcommand{\jubo@chaptercomplete}{\thechapter\chapterextra}
  \fi%
  }

%%% Eintrag der Kapitel ohne Nummer im TOC auch fett
\renewcommand{\jb@tocextras@style}{\normalfont\bfseries}

%%% Autor in Normalgröße
\renewcommand*{\jb@author@style}{\normalsize}

%%% Voreinstellung für Titelseite
\def\@title{Hausarbeit}

\def\@shortauthor{\@empty}
\let\@@@author\author
\def\author{\@ifnextchar[{\@@author}{\@@@author}}
\def\@@author[#1]#2{\gdef\@shortauthor{#1}\@@@author{#2}}
%%% Neue Befehle für die Titelseite
\def\@semester{}
\def\@fachsemester{}
\def\semester{\@ifnextchar[{\@@semester}{\@@@semester}}
\def\@@semester[#1]#2{\gdef\@fachsemester{#1}\gdef\@semester{#2}}
\def\@@@semester#1{\gdef\@semester{#1}}

\def\@prof{}
\def\prof#1{\gdef\@prof{#1}}

\def\@matrikelnummer{}
\def\matrikelnummer#1{\gdef\@matrikelnummer{#1}}

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
  \begin{titlepage}%
    \let\footnotesize\small
    \let\footnoterule\relax
    \let\footnote\thanks
    {\jb@author@style
       \if@headlinetitlepageleft\else\hfill\fi
       \begin{tabular}[t]{l}%
         \@author%
         \ifx\@matrikelnummer\@empty\else\tabularnewline\@matrikelnummer\fi%
         \ifx\@fachsemester\@empty\else\tabularnewline\@fachsemester\fi%
       \end{tabular}\par%
      }
    \null\vfil%
    %\vskip 60\p@
    \begin{center}%
      {\jb@title@style\vskip 2ex \@title\par}%
      \ifx\@subtitle\@empty% \ifthenelse funzt hier nicht wg. moegl. '\\'
      \else
        {\jb@subtitle@style\vskip 4ex\@subtitle \par}%
      \fi%
      \vskip 1ex%
      {\ifx\@prof\@empty%
       \else\jb@subtitle@style Bei\ \@prof \par\fi}
       \vskip 2ex
      {\jb@subtitle@style \@semester}
      \vskip 4ex
      {\jb@titledate@style\@date\par}%
    \end{center}\par
    %{\jb@thanks@style\@thanks\par}
    \vfil\null%
    \@emptytitles
  \end{titlepage}%
  \setcounter{page}{2} %%% damit die Seitenzählung korrekt ist
}%

\renewcommand{\@emptytitles}{%
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
  \global\let\thanks\relax
  \global\let\maketitle\relax
  \global\let\@thanks\@empty
  \global\let\@author\@empty
  \global\let\@date\@empty
  \global\let\@title\@empty
  \global\let\title\relax
  \global\let\author\relax
  \global\let\date\relax
  \global\let\and\relax
  \global\let\@subtitle\@empty
  \global\let\@publishinfo\@empty
  \global\let\@birthplace\@empty
  \global\let\@publishplace\@empty
  \global\let\@publishyear\@empty
  \global\let\@firstexaminer\@empty
  \global\let\@secondexaminer\@empty
  \global\let\@examdate\@empty
  \global\let\subtitle\relax
  \global\let\publishinfo\relax
  \global\let\birthplace\relax
  \global\let\publishplace\relax
  \global\let\publishyear\relax
  \global\let\firstexaminer\relax
  \global\let\secondexaminer\relax
  \global\let\examdate\relax%
  \global\let\@semester\@empty
  \global\let\@prof\@empty
  \global\let\semester\relax
  \global\let\prof\relax
}

\def\@setsize#1#2#3#4{%
  % Modified 1993.04.07--GDG per KPC
  \@nomath#1%
  \let\@currsize#1%
  \baselineskip #2%
  \baselineskip \baselinestretch\baselineskip
  \parskip \baselinestretch\parskip
  \setbox\strutbox \hbox{%
    \vrule height.7\baselineskip
           depth.3\baselineskip
           width\z@}%
  \skip\footins \baselinestretch\skip\footins
  \normalbaselineskip\baselineskip#3#4}

\let\@ORIGgeometry\geometry
\renewcommand\geometry[1]{\@ORIGgeometry{#1}%
    \setlength{\marginparwidth}{.6\oddsidemargin}%
    \addtolength{\marginparwidth}{1in}}

\let\frqq\glqq
\let\flqq\grqq
\tolerance 1414
\hbadness 1414
\emergencystretch 1.5em
\hfuzz 0.3pt
\clubpenalty=5000
\widowpenalty=9999
\vfuzz \hfuzz
\raggedbottom
%% 
%% Originally developed by Martin Sievers (martin.sievers@schoenerpublizieren.de)
%% Copyright (C) 2012-2016 by Martin Sievers
%% 
%% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
%% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License (LPPL), either
%% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any later
%% version. The latest version of this license is in the file:
%% 
%%  http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%% 
%% This work is "maintained" (as per LPPL maintenance status) by
%%   Martin Sievers (martin.sievers@schoenerpublizieren.de).
%% 
%% This work consists of the file  hausarbeit-jura.dtx
%%                                 hausarbeit-jura.ins
%%                                 README.md
%%           and the derived files hausarbeit-jura.pdf
%%                                 hausarbeit-jura.cls
%%                                 hausarbeit-demo.tex
%%                                 hausarbeit-demo.bib
%% 
%%
%% End of file `hausarbeit-jura.cls'.
```

Comment: Off-topic: If you think `\onehalfspace` would produce 1.5 MS-Word skips ... well, fill in yourself ;-)

Comment: No need to modify the `onehalfspacing` environment. Just issue the directive `\setstretch{1.5}` (or whatever the most suitable value may be).

Comment: It is almost always a bad idea to modify a package and save teh fiel as the same name. If you really want to edit the settings save the command as a different name say `texnewbie.sty` and use it as `\usepackage{texnewbie}`  instead of `\usepackage{setspace}`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Can you please explain what you mean?

Comment: @Mico I got trouble as soon as I tried to load `\usepackage{setspace}` I received the command already defined error

Comment: @texnewbie: You should not compare TeX line spacings with MS Word line spacings!

Comment: You don't need to post the class above it is in the standard distributions already, it includes `/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/juramisc/jurabook.cls:` which has `\providecommand{\onehalfspacing}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I changed the name and loaded it. I don't get the error anymore. But the `\setstretch{1.433}`is still not being applied.

Comment: I didn't suggest you modify `\setstretch`. Instead, I suggested you issue the directive `\setstretch{1.5}` -- ideally immediately after `\begin{document}`.

Comment: I don't see anywhere that you are using `\onehalfspacing` so where would you expect it to be applied? the package only defines the command

Comment: how did you calculate the factors such as 1.448? they seem rather strange numbers?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I put the `\onehalfspacing`after the first chapter. I got it from following website http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/3/wie-stelle-ich-einen-zeilenabstand-von-15-ein?

Comment: But if I compared a 1.5 MSWORD PDF with the compiled 1.433 12pt pdf it seemed to fit

Comment: Your posted code doesn't have `\chapter` or `\onehalfspacing`

Comment: but as mico says, you do not need to redefine `\onehalfspacing` just use `setstretch {1.433}` instead of `\onehalfspacing` in your document.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I updated it to feature the full code. This was the first thing I tried. Using `\setstretch{1.433}` without redefining `\onehalfspacing`. But always when I tried to load `\usepackage{setspace}`I got the command already defined error.

Comment: @texnewbie - It sounds like the document class already loads the `setspace` package. If that's the case, why do you try to load it again?

Comment: @Mico Because if I don't load `setspace`. I get the undefined control sequence error when using `setstretch{1.433}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jurabook` class does

```
\providecommand{\onehalfspacing}{% 
  \normalsize
  \ifthenelse{\@ptsize = 0}% 10pt
    {\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25}}%
    {}
  \ifthenelse{\@ptsize = 1}% 11pt
    {\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.21}}%
    {}
  \ifthenelse{\@ptsize = 2}% 12pt
    {\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.24}}%
    {}
  \normalsize  
}
```

so you don't need `setspace` package you can just use in your own package
with whatever numbers you need.

```
\renewcommand{\onehalfspacing}{% 
  \normalsize
  \ifthenelse{\@ptsize = 0}% 10pt
    {\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25}}%
    {}
  \ifthenelse{\@ptsize = 1}% 11pt
    {\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.21}}%
    {}
  \ifthenelse{\@ptsize = 2}% 12pt
    {\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.24}}%
    {}
  \normalsize  
}
```

Comment: I added `\makeatletter` before and `\makeatother` after. Now I only need to figure out how to apply this only to the desired part. Because in the beginning I need regular spacing.

Comment: @texnewbie if you put this in a package file as suggested you do not need and should not use `\makeat....`